# Color or Colour?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spelling

Which word is most accurate among `Color` and `Colour`? Is there any difference in the ancestry of these words?

Also if I want to use the word in a professional emails or in official communications through read-write which word should I use?

Comment: Neither. It's "[colour](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/colour?showCookiePolicy=true)" in British English and "color" in American English. But never with capital 'C'. Which variety you use is your choice - but it's probably a good idea to choose *one* English and stick with it.

Comment: @Stephie If the question on-topic, would you consider posting an answer for completeness? :)

Comment: If it is Off topic then should I post it in StackOverflow or what?

Answer (score 4):

Neither. It's "colour" in British English and "color" in American English. But never with capital 'C'.

Which variety you use is your choice - but it's probably a good idea to choose one English and stick with it. "favourite color" would be wrong both in the US and GB.

There are quite a few other words with different spelling in BrE vs. AmE, the main differences stem from a spelling reform in the US (19th century) with, for example, the following changes:

- words ending with  -**re** -> -**re**

  - centre / center
  - kilometre / kilometer
  - litre / liter
- words ending with  -**our** -> -**or** (or derrived words)

  - colour / color
  - flavour / flavor
  - favourite / favorite
- words ending with  -**ogue** -> -**og**

  - dialogue / dialog
- words ending with  -**ence** -> -**ense**

  - licence / license
- words ending with  -**ise** or -**ize** -> -**ise** only

  - realize or realise / realise
- and others.

More on this topic at [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/british-and-american-spelling) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences)